# Compare string in two files And Merge its Output

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, scripting

I am trying to get the bandwidth of the domain from one file and its hits details from another file.

The format of the two files is as follows:

1. bandwidth.txt

   ```
   aadrivingschool.ws       2840.36M
   aaspak.org               211.57M
   aasteknik.com            1419.26M
   aatonerpk.com            14.87M
   ```
2. hits.txt:

   ```
   onlinestudyboard.com   received  186     hits  from  31/May/2016  at  1201
   aaspak.org             received  184     hits  from  31/May/2016  at  1202
   khawajarubber.com      received  183     hits  from  31/May/2016  at  1246
   aatonerpk.com          received  182     hits  from  31/May/2016  at  1231
   ```

What I'm trying to to get is:

```
onlinestudyboard.com       received  186     hits  from  31/May/2016  at  1201 
aaspak.org                 received  184     hits  from  31/May/2016  at  1202  211.57M
khawajarubber.com          received  183     hits  from  31/May/2016  at  1246
aatonerpk.com              received  182     hits  from  31/May/2016  at  1231  14.87M
```

Comment: I have searched but didn't get any suitable solution.

Comment: It's essentially the same as the duplicate. You just need to run `join <(sort bandwidth.txt) <(sort hits.txt)`. Note that it won't produce the output you show since you don't have the same domains in the two files. It will only print output for those domains that are in both files. If you need something more, please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: Thanks terdon, but i have already  tried that command you have mentioned. I want the output as mentioned in question.

Comment: you can try: join -a 1 <(sort hits.txt) <(sort bandwidth.txt )

Comment: thanks hameeddullah, its working but it disturb my data position:

aaspak.org received 150 hits from 31/May/2016 at 12:15:54AM to 02:08:34PM 211.57M
onlinestudyboard.com received 162 hits from 31/May/2016 at 12:01:00AM to 02:49:26PM 14M
khawajarubber.com received 162 hits from 31/May/2016 at 12:01:14AM to 02:56:46PM

Comment: @rlinux in that case, please [edit] your question and clarify what you need. It's very easy to miss if you don't scroll to the right to see your output and, in any case, it is better to both show *and* explain. It looks like you want all lines from `hits.txt` to be printed and to also print the associated bandwidth when available. Is that correct? If so, tell us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an `awk` approach:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next} {print $0,a[$1]}' bandwidth.txt hits.txt
onlinestudyboard.com     received  186     hits  from  31/May/2016  at  1201 
aaspak.org               received  184     hits  from  31/May/2016  at  1202 211.57M
khawajarubber.com        received  183     hits  from  31/May/2016  at  1246 
aatonerpk.com            received  182     hits  from  31/May/2016  at  1231 14.87M
```

#### Explanation

`awk` reads its input file(s) line by line, and split the line into fields at whitespace (or whatever is given by `-F`). These fields are then `$1`,$2`...`$N`.

- `NR==FNR` : NR is the current line number, FNR is the line number of the current file. The two will be identical only while the 1st file is being read.
- `a[$1]=$2; next` : if this is the first file (see above), save the 2nd field in an array whose key is the 1st field.
- `print $0,a[$1]` : print the current line (`$0`) and the value in the `a` array associated with the first field. This will print the current line of the second file along with any value from the first file associated with its 1st field.

Answer (score 0):

With **sort***ed* **join**, **column** and a few **bash**_isms:

```bash
join -a 1 <(sort hits.txt) <(sort bandwidth.txt) | column -t | sort -nrk3
```

Three sorts are needed.  Two because the input files aren't sorted by common fields, but **join** needed sorted input.  Another **sort** (3rd field, reverse numeric) is needed to restore the OP sort order.

Output:

```
onlinestudyboard.com  received  186  hits  from  31/May/2016  at  1201
aaspak.org            received  184  hits  from  31/May/2016  at  1202  211.57M
khawajarubber.com     received  183  hits  from  31/May/2016  at  1246
aatonerpk.com         received  182  hits  from  31/May/2016  at  1231  14.87M
```

---

The code is simpler when the output order is not significant, and the input files *are* presorted:

```sh
join -a 1 hits.txt bandwidth.txt | column -t
```